# CUDA segmentation fault for trivial tutorial example

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to run the example `add.cu` (see below) from [this official nvidia tutorial](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/) using `nvcc add.cu -o add_cuda; ./add_cuda` and get  `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I installed the nvidia cuda toolkit on Ubuntu 18 using `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. I have a NVIDIA GF100GL Quadro 5000 and am using  `NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested)`

I have little C++ experience, but the pure C++ code from the beginning of the tutorial compiled and ran correctly.

Following a comment, I added a check for the return of `cudaMallocManaged` and got `operation not supported`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *y;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate driver and hardware?

Comment: @molbdnilo I think so, check the edit

Comment: You should check the error returns from cudaMallocManaged(). You can also use gdb to see where the program crashed.

Comment: @TungLeThanh I got the following `CUDA ERROR operation not supported at line 20's cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float))
CUDA ERROR operation not supported at line 21's cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float))`

Comment: It is 99% likely that your GPU isn't supported by the CUDA version you have installed

Comment: What command line options are you using to compile with, are you specifying a compute model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your card belongs to fermi family with compute capability version 2.0. It does not support the Unified Memory as stated [here:](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd)

> ### K.1.1. System Requirements
>
> Unified Memory has two basic requirements:
>
> > a GPU with SM architecture 3.0 or higher (Kepler class or newer)
> >
> > a 64-bit host application and non-embedded operating system (Linux, Windows, macOS)

Comment: Oh thanks for googling that for me. I had only checked that it's CUDA able , didn't know untied memory had more restrictions